# How to replace line items with individual result in jQuery

Tags: jquery, ajax, fadein

I have a list of search results, with embedded links that take you to an individual result detail. However, the details are small, and I would like to do an in-place substitution of the linked para with the result detail. So user searches, gets a list of results, clicks on link for one of the results, and the result detail fades in below that item.

The result list is already the result of an ajax call:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'html',
  cache: false,
  url:  'search.php',
  data: terms,
  success: function(result) { 
    var details = $("#results",result).html();
    $("#results").html(details).fadeIn('slow');                         
    $('a',"#results").click(function(e) { 
      e.preventDefault();
      alert('bingo!'); /* this where I need to set up the replacement I guess */
    }); 
  }
});
```

with the `<a>` tag already set up to find the result:

```
<a href="search.php?id=1409">
```

which I'd like to use to fetch the inline replacement. Half my problem is understanding how to get the detail to fade in!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.load()` . It does the equivalent of `.html()` and `.ajax()` combined together.

Short Example:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
   cache:false,
   type: "GET"
});

$("#results a").click(function(){
    $("#results").hide(0).load('search.php', terms).fadeIn('slow'); 
});
```

http://api.jquery.com/load#urldatacallback

Comment: but the search requires the parameters from the link?

Comment: So the downvote? You can certainly pass parameters into the `data` parameter. Did you try reading the documentation?

Comment: $('answer').patronise().whine().rtfm() ? Yeah, down vote - I didn't find it helpful.

Comment: @Dycey: You don't need to explicitly pass `dataType` and `type`. They are defaults. And, `cache` property can be set via global ajax settings.

Comment: I hope I have answered your question now.

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of completeness, the code I ended up using was:

```
$('a',"#results").click(function(e) { 
  e.preventDefault(); 
  var link = this; 
  var para = $(link).parent();
  var my_id = $(link).attr("href").match(/\d+/);
  $('<div id="results_'+my_id+'">').insertAfter(para);
  $('#results_'+my_id).hide().load("search.php #results > table", {id:my_id}).fadeIn('slow').slideDown('slow');
  $(link).unbind('click').click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); 
    $('#results_'+my_id).toggle();
  });
});
```

However, for for the sake of fairness, and despite not really answering the question, I've given the vote to conqenator as he seems to need it more than me ;-)